# Python call inner function

Tags: python

I have the following problem:

I have a function that holds another function inside (see code bellow). I need to call the function getFastaEntry with a parameter filename set in the top level function.I tried to call it with generate_fasta_reader(filename).getFastaEntry(), but I get the error message "function object has no attribute getFastaEntry()". Can anybody tell me how I can call the inner function?

```
def generate_fasta_reader(filename, gzipped=False, strip=True):

    def getFastaEntry():
        filehandle = None
```

Comment: You would just do `getFastaEntry(filename)` inside `generate_fasta_reader` (after the `def getFastaEntry`).  As written, there's no reason for this to be an inner function, especially since it looks like you're trying to call it from an outer scope.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunatally it is given code that I have to keep. I also see no reason to do it this way...

Answer (score 4):

You must *return* the inner function. It's not accessible otherwise and in fact ceases to exist as soon as the function ends, because there are no references to it at that point. The parameters of the outer function are available to the inner function via a closure. (I assume your actual `getFastaEntry()` function actually does something besides assign a local variable that goes out of scope almost immediately.)

```
def generate_fasta_reader(filename, gzipped=False, strip=True):

    def getFastaEntry():
        filehandle = None

    return getFastaEntry
```

Calling:

```
getter = generate_fasta_reader("foo.txt")
getter()
```

Or in one step (if you only need it call the inner function once per outer function call):

```
generate_fasta_reader("foo.txt")()
```

Comment: Thank you! It works :). And yes the inner function does something - I just thought it would be easier to answer if i keep it short.